# Comparing chars together?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and have run into a problem when trying to compare two chars, here is an example:

```
#define PartOne "He"
#define PartTwo "llo"
char Final1Var[] = PartOne PartTwo;
char ComapreVars[] = "Hello";

if(Final1Var == ComapreVars)//This is were the problem occurs, the chars are supposed to be equal to each other BUT for some reason the 'if' statement ends up determining they're not?
   InGameDialog::Alert("They Match");
else
    InGameDialog::Alert("They Don't Match");
```

What is going wrong with the code? I can't imagine why this wouldn't work? Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to look at [strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: This is not `cimparing two chars`. This is comparing two *C-style character arrays*. Use `std::string` instead for your string-related needs.

Answer (score -1):

in c++ character array's could not be compared using ==  operator you have to use strcmp function or string comparison function.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very common question.  I'll mark it as duplicate once I find a good answer to this among the other questions.

In the mean time, you're not comparing `char`s, you're comparing `char[]`s, which is entirely different.  You'll want to use strcmp, strncmp, or std::string types would be an even better solution.

[What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) has some reasonable explanations for what's going on in your code and why.